# Angular UI Select, undefined ng-model

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-ui

I have below code from example of Angular UI Select:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="SelectedItem" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors">{{color}} Cool</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
<p>Selected: {{SelectedItem}}</p>
```

And nd-model didnt define any scope variable. `<p>` show only 'Selected: ' and in controller variable $scope.SelectedItem is undefined. The rest is working fine.

Comment: so what it the problem

Comment: i guess problem is what i describe. no-model did not difine a variable in $scope

Comment: you havent given values to ui-select?

Comment: i have. Tried with one value and multiple values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, i had to define mine scope variable in controller first. Something like that: `$scope.SelectedItem = {};`
That's was something that was nowhere before Angular-UI and was not clear from main page of Angular-UI.